# AC on driver's side is bad.

Tags: ac, mercedes-benz

I have Mercedes E350 2009. On driver's side, AC is not as cold as the passenger's side (second and back). Also, AC is much colder when air intake is set to inside but every five minutes it disconnects and sets air intake to outside. How serious is the problem here?

Comment: Not blowing cold on both sides sounds like a blend door problem. There are actuators on both sides (pass/driver's) which adjusts doors that regulate the amount of hot/cold air being driven out by the fan motor. The one on the driver's side would probably be bad or not allowing the blend door to move completely. No clue on what's going on with your second issue. Probably take a diagnostic as Allan suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a scan on your AirCon electrics, as well as an AirCon service check over with a service grade/garage machine. Your problem could be with one or the other.